# How to Fill the placeholder of the Body in asp.net Core MVC?

Tags: css, asp.net-core-mvc

From a [documentation](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/layout-view-in-asp.net-mvc)  ,  i learned that **RenderBody** method return views inside the *placeholder* of the layout , as this schema show:

[image]

however,practically wasn't as it is expected, i created a layout with a navbar and a footer and i added a view which contains a div  this is what it return a gap between my view and the footer :

[image]

So how to fill this gap ? i tried to give max height to my div but that dosen't worked !
this is the code of my view :

```
  @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    }

<div  style="background-color:white;width:970px;height:100%; border:11px solid black">
   <img src="~/images/decoupage/header-img.png" />
   <h3 style="color:blue">Qui somme nous ?</h3>

   <p style="background-color:white">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
    in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.

  </p>
   <img src="~/images/decoupage/img1.png" style="padding-left:60px;padding-bottom:50px" />

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved , the solution was :

1) make the min-height of the body equal to 100vh (so it fills the screen)

2) use flexbox on the body :

```
 <body class="bg-secondary" style="margin-bottom:0; min-height:100vh; display:flex;flex-direction:column">
```

and choose the direction of flex to be  **column**

3) use flexbox on the div parent of the main section and set flex to 1 so it fills the gap in the body :

4) use flexbox on the main section and set the flex to 1:

```
<div class="container " style="min-height:100%; padding-left:120px;flex:1;display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
    <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />
    <main role="main"  style="flex:1;display:flex;flex-direction:column;">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>
```

5) finally set flex to 1 in the child of the main section (the view) :

```
  main > div {
        flex:1;  
    }
```